# Spawn multiple threads that take inputs from single collection and put results in single collection

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is a brief of what i want to do , I have a scenario where

1. number of text files are generated dynamically on daily basis. 0
   to 8 per day. size of each file can be small to big. depending on
   day's data.
2. Need to run some checks  (business checks) on them.

I plan to complete the task in minimum time, hence trying to write a parallel executor for performing checks on these files.

My idea is

1. Store n files in a concurrent collection (ConcurrentLinkedQueue)
2. remove a file, spawn a thread , that runs all checks on the file
3. since 1 file has no relation to another i want to be able to process multiple files
4. Store results in another concurrent collection ( ConcurrentLinkedQueue ... which is converted to different html pdf reports)
5. NOTE : number of threads can be different from number of files (I want to number of threads configurable , its not the case where number of file = number of threads )

My understanding is This way i should be able to complete the DAILY checks in minimum time.

I have my code like below , **what confuses me** "how to store all thread's results in single collection after each thread's completion" , my gut feeling is i am doing something funny (incorrect) the way i am storing results.

**Second ques** wanted to check if anyone forsees any other issues in code snippet below

**Third ques** this seems like a common use case ( to me ) any pointers to design pattern code snippets solving this

**Note** : i am using JDK 6.

```
public class CheckExecutor {
    // to store all results of all threads here , then this will be converted to html/pdf files
    static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result> fileWiseResult = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfThreads=n; // need keep it configurable
        Collection<ABCCheck> checksToExecute // will populate from business logic , ABCCheck is interface , has a method check() , there are different implementations

        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<File> fileQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<File>(); // list of files for 1 day , may vary from 0 to 8
        int maxNumOfFiles = fileQueue.size();

        ThreadGroup tg = new ThreadGroup ("Group");
        // If more number of threads than files (rare , can be considered corener case)
        if (maxNumOfFiles < numberOfThreads) numberOfThreads=maxNumOfFiles;
        // loop and start number of threads
        for(int var=0;var<numberOfThreads;var++) 
        {
            File currentFile = fileQueue.remove();
            // execute all checks on 1 file using checksToExecute
            ExecuteAllChecks checksToRun = new ExecuteAllChecks(); // business logic to populate checks
            checksToRun.setchecksToExecute(checksToExecute);
            checksToRun.setcheckResult(fileWiseResult); // when each check finishes want to store result here
            new Thread (tg , checksToRun , "Threads for "+currentFile.getName()).start();
        }

        // To complete the tasak ... asap ... want to start a new thread as soon as any of current thread ends (diff files diff sizes)
        while(!fileQueue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000); // Not sure If this will cause main thread to sleep (i think it will pause current thread ) i want to pause main thread
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // check processing of how many files completed
            if( (tg.activeCount()<numberOfThreads) && (fileQueue.size()>0) ) {
                int numOfThreadsToStart = numberOfThreads - tg.activeCount();
                for(int var1=0;var1<numOfThreadsToStart;var1++) {
                    File currentFile = fileQueue.remove();
                    ExecuteAllchecks checksToRun = new ExecuteAllchecks();
                    checksToRun.setchecksToExecute(checksToExecute);
                    checksToRun.setcheckResult(fileWiseResult); // when each check finishes want to store result here
                    new Thread (tg , checksToRun , "Threads for "+currentFile.getName()).start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ExecuteAllchecks implements Runnable {

    private Collection<ABCCheck> checksToExecute;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result> checkResult; // not sure if its correct , i want to store result off all threads here

    public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result> getcheckResult() {
        return checkResult;
    }

    // plan to instantiate the result collection globally and store result here
    public void setcheckResult(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result> checkResult) {
        this.checkResult = checkResult;
    }

    public Collection<ABCCheck> getchecksToExecute() {
        return checksToExecute;
    }

    public void setchecksToExecute(Collection<ABCCheck> checksToExecute) {
        this.checksToExecute = checksToExecute;
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        Result currentFileResult = new Result();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Execute All checks for 1 file");
        // each check runs and calls setters on currentFileResult
        checkResult.add(currentFileResult);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow.  You really should look into the `ExecutorService` classes.  I think a service returning results from submitted `Callable` classes would be better.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Comment: I also can't tell if you need an `ExecutorCompletionService` or not.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Comment: I used for similar task different simpler approach: main thread starts runners and passes them queue with files and then join them to wait till them exit. Every runner polls a file from queue, processes it, polls another one process it ... till the queue is empty. When queue is empty the runner finish run() method so it finished and when all runners are done the main thread continue.

Comment: Thanks Gray , ExecutorCompletionService  worked for me

Answer (score 3):

The actual implementation is very influenced by the nature of the computations itself, but somewhat general approach could be:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private final int taskCount = ...;
private void process() {
  Collection< Callable< Result > > tasks = new ArrayList<>( taskCount );
  for( int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++ ) {
      tasks.add( new Callable< Result >() {

        @Override
        public Result call() throws Exception {
            // TODO implement your logic and return result
            ...
            return result;
        }

      } );
  }
  List< Future< Result > > futures = executor.invokeAll( tasks );
  List< Result > results = new ArrayList<>( taskCount );
  for( Future< Result > future : futures ) {
      results.add( future.get() );
  }
}
```

I would also recommend using sensible timeouts on `future.get()` invocations in order to executing thread not to stuck.

Still, I would't also recommend using cached thread pool in production as this pool is increasing whenever current pool doesn't have enough capacity for all tasks, but rather using something like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool( Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() )`

I you actual task could be splitter into several small ones and the later be joined consider checking how that could be efficiently be done using [ForkJoin framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)

Comment: Good answer, but I would probably post the results somewhere instead of waiting in order for all results to complete. So that if file 1 is very big I already get the result for file 2.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about unblocking solution and the only thing I could come up with would using a shared resource but still I you need to get all the results (of course if there's no additional processing required with the obtained results) you'll be waiting for the same amount of time as in this solution. That is with blocking approach you'll block on the longest one but if other results are ready by that time future will return immediately.